# Android Compling time error

Tags: android

THis is the error what i am getting
In mobile its saying that unfortunately stoped

```
7-18 17:19:58.769 20914-20914/com.oakridgebs.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.oakridgebs.myapplication, PID: 20914
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oakridgebs.myapplication/com.oakridgebs.myapplication.FdActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
        at com.oakridgebs.myapplication.FdActivity.onCreate(FdActivity.java:181)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944) 
        at com.oakridgebs.myapplication.FdActivity.onCreate(FdActivity.java:181) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06005d a=-1 r=0x7f06005d}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2124)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944) 
        at com.oakridgebs.myapplication.FdActivity.onCreate(FdActivity.java:181) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please show your layout

Comment: Please post xml code

Comment: Resource is missing. check if the resources are in proper place.